# go test coverprofile cannot find package

Tags: go

When I try the following

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out
```

I get this coverage.out:

```
mode: set
_/Users/gert/Desktop/httx/auth.go:10.66,11.54 1 0
_/Users/gert/Desktop/httx/auth.go:11.54,13.89 2 0
_/Users/gert/Desktop/httx/auth.go:17.3,17.11 1 0
_/Users/gert/Desktop/httx/auth.go:13.89,16.4 2 0
_/Users/gert/Desktop/httx/auth.go:22.42,25.2 2 0
...
```

But when I then do

```
go tool cover -func=coverage.out
```

coverage.out doesn't seem to be correctly formatted?

```
cover: can't find "auth.go": cannot find package "_/Users/gert/Desktop/httx/" in any of:                                     
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.1/libexec/src/_/Users/gert/Desktop/httx (from $GOROOT)                                      
        /Users/gert/go/src/_/Users/gert/Desktop/httx (from $GOPATH)
```

EDIT: Note that `go test -cover` works.

```
PASS                                                                                                                         
coverage: 29.7% of statements                                                                                                
ok      _/Users/gert/Desktop/httx       0.015s
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your package `/Users/gert/Desktop/httx/` is outside of your `$GOPATH` which is `/Users/gert/go`. Move the `httx` package somewhere under your `$GOPATH` and it will work fine. You could move it to `/Users/gert/go/src/httx` or probably something like `/Users/gert/go/src/github.com/your-github-name/httx` (assuming you use GitHub).

Comment: Ok, but why does go test -cover manage to give me a percentage?

Comment: @GertCuykens I'm just speculating here but I'd say it's because when you run `go test` it knows the code it's testing but when you try to run `go tool cover` later it has to go off the package names in the `coverage.out` and can't find them.

Comment: Ok thanks your answer is correct but I am going to create a feature request on github I think for this because for me it's counter intuitive to be forced to put your src it in gopath just for the cover tool

Answer (score 3):

see [use relative path](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22430#issuecomment-414668599)

change coverage path to `./` :

```
sed -i "s/_$(pwd|sed 's/\//\\\//g')/./g" coverage.out
```